# Testing HTTPS on Sinatra locally

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin

I need to test how some elements on my page behave when I access it over HTTPS - I was wondering how I could test this sinatra app locally with HTTPS. I apologize if my question doesn't even make sense, but I would like to connect to localhost through my web browser over HTTPS.

Comment: What web server are you running Sinatra through?

Comment: @Larsenal thin. So maybe this is a thin question?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: You can create a self-signed certificate for local development.  Heroku has a brief article on [how to create a self-signed SSL cert](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self).

Once you've created your cert and key, it's pretty simple with Thin:

```
SSL options:
    --ssl                        Enables SSL
    --ssl-key-file PATH          Path to private key
    --ssl-cert-file PATH         Path to certificate
    --ssl-verify                 Enables SSL certificate verification
```

Comment: `bundle exec thin start -p 3001 -R config.ru --ssl --ssl-key-file ~/.ssl/server.key --ssl-cert-file ~/.ssl/server.crt` worked for me